# Power BI premium limits

Tags: powerbi

Looking at this page: [Power BI features comparison](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/#powerbi-comparison-table) I see that a dataset can be 10gb and storage is limited to 100tb.  Can I take this to mean there is a limit of 10,000 10gb apps?

Also is there a limit on the number of users?  It implies no with the statement "Licensed by dedicated cloud compute and storage resources", but I wanted to be sure.

I assume I am paying for compute so the real limits are based on what compute resources I purchase?  Are there any limits on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have 10,000 10GB datasets, to use up the total volume of 100TB, however storage will also be used for Excel Workbooks, Dataflows storage, as well as Excel ranges pinned to a dashboard, and other uploaded images.

There is no limit on the total number of users, however there is a limit based on 'peak renders per hour', which means how often users interact with the report. PBI Premium does expect you you have a mix of frequent and infrequent users, so for Premium P1 nodes, the peak renders per hour is 1 to 2400. Anything over that, you may experience performance degradation on that node is for example you had 3500 renders of a report in an hour, but it will depend on the type of report, queries etc. You can scale up to quite a number of nodes if you need to, [Power BI Premium Gen 2](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-upcoming-evolution-of-power-bi-premium-to-enterprise-markets-and-beyond/) does allow auto scale.